# Accessing GPIO throgh /dev/mem is it safer?

Tags: linux, embedded, embedded-linux, imx6

I am doing a project where the gpio switching should be fast like 40MHz speed. I checked with "sysfs" interface and the switching speed is around 300Hz. It is not at all acceptable in our case. 
So, in some forums I read using /dev/mem access will increase the switching speed. I used /dev/mem and the achieved the speed 30-32MHz and it is OK for us. Now the project is going for field testing, will it cause any issue like kernel crash something like that in long run.

Comment: How can we tell without seeing the code?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, i.mx6 does not have atomic pin set/reset functionality, therefore you must assure that all GPIO output pins are controlled by your application, **neither the kernel nor another process should ever attempt to change any output pin on the same GPIO controller**. Reading input pins, or assigning some pins to other periperals should be OK, but always ensure that no bit-banging happens behind the scenes (e.g. some SPI drivers think that they know better when to set or reset CS, and quietly set the CS pin to GPIO output, taking it away from the SPI peripheral)

**You can sustain that output speed as long as your process is not interrupted.** If you don't disable interrupts, you will get glitches in the output. If you do, then the kernel scheduler and interrupt-driven hardware drivers stop working. On a dual or quad core system, it should be possible to reserve a core for exclusive use by your process, and let the rest of the system run on the other core(s). Don't just blindly disable interrupts, but use [`sched_setaffinity(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sched_setaffinity.2.html#NOTES) and the `isolcpus` kernel parameter.

Comment: I am sure that I am not using the GPIO controller anywhere except in /dev/mem.